# Decrypting files that were encrypted with EFS?

Tags: decryption, efs

I was wondering if there was a way to decrypt files that were decrypted with efs. I have an external drive with encrypted files that were taken from an old computer. I have the certificate and I believe the private key as well, I'm just not sure how to tie it all together to decrypt the file(s). I've tried googling and had no luck.

Answer (score 2):

You would import the keys to the right key store via MMC snap in and then mount the file system and decrypt. As described [here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/77268-import-encrypting-file-system-certificate-key-windows-10-a.html). An external program may also do this for you as described [here](https://support.accessdata.com/hc/en-us/articles/203777075-Decrypting-EFS) for FTK.